# Staying on page after submitting

Tags: php, jquery, html

just a question --

How do i actually submit a form and still stay on the same page whilst the script is being executed?

I have a simple form that goes like this:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" id="form">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required="required" />
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required="required" />
    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" required="required" />
    <label for="message">Message</label>
    <input type="text" name="message" id="message" required="required" />
    <input type="submit" id="button" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

But everytime i submit the form it just goes to process.php. I don't want that, i want it to stay on the same page, maybe even have a jquery popup saying "thank you" or something.

How do i actually stay on the same page whilst the script is being run?

Comment: If you are not on the same page as process.php, ajax is the only way to go. If you are on the same page as process.php, use something like srini's approach to post-back to the same page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Put your form processing logic on the same page as the form
2. Use Ajax
3. Redirect back to that page when process.php is done processing the form

Comment: I guess Ajax response will be automatically back to the page which request it. So redirect seems a bit fuzzy.

Comment: jQuery Ajax would be the best way to do it. There's a zillion tutorials about how to do it so I'll leave it to you to find the one that explains it to your liking.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use ajax in this case.

Basically, you need to post all data using ajax. In server side, you will need to get all parameters using $_POST['name'] like you normally do in server scripting.

FORM

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" id="form">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required="required" />
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required="required" />
    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" required="required" />
    <label for="message">Message</label>
    <input type="text" name="message" id="message" required="required" />
    <input type="button" id="button" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<div id="dialog-message" title="Thank You">
    <p>Your message here</p>
</div>

​
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#dialog-message').dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });



    $('#button').on('click', function() {
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var subject = $('#subject').val();
        var message = $('#message').val();
        var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&subject=' + subject + '&message=' + message;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function() {
                alert('');
                $('#dialog-message').dialog('open');
            }
        });
    });
});​
```

See the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GqL48/2/)

Please note, dont forget to put jquery reference and also jquery ui reference

Comment: Note that you can just use `$("#form").serialize()` instead of manually constructing the string.

Answer (score 2):

I think John Conde gave the best answer.

I would either make it so the php file that displays the form also handles the $_POST or if you can't do it that way then do it in Ajax with a code similar to this:

```
$("#form").bind("submit", function() { 

var nameTxt = $("#name").val();
var emailTxt = $("#email").val();
$.post('process.php', 
    {
        name: nameTxt,
        email: emailTxt
    }, 
    function(data) {
                if (data == 'ko')
                    alert('Could not submit...');
                else {
                    alert('Thank you for your message.');
                }
            });
return false;
}
```

What this does is that it "blocks" the regular submit of the form when you click the submit button, retrieve input values and sends them to the process.php script.

It assumes that your "process.php" does an

```
 echo "ko";
```

if there is an error. You can do some form cleanup after the form has been successfully sent by reseting the inputs:

```
$("#name").val('');
$("#email").val('');
```

Answer (score 2):

I targeted an iframe to solve the problem, and it worked perfectly.

```html
<form name="contact" role="form" method="post" action="contact.php" target="my_iframe">
      
  Feild 1: <input name="feild1" id="feild1" type="text" placeholder="Lorem ipsum dolor"><br/><br/>
  Feild 2: <input name="feild2" id="feild2" type="text" placeholder="Lorem ipsum dolor"><br/><br/>
  Feild 3: <textarea name="feild3" id="feild3" rows="5" type="text" placeholder="Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet."></textarea><br/><br/>
  <input type="submit">
      
</form>

<!-- target iframe to prevent redirection to 'contact.php' -->
<iframe name="my_iframe" width="1" height="1" style="border:none"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#form').submit(function(e){
    // do some ajax request to process.php here...

    // stop the form doing its default action of submitting directly to process.php
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't actually submit the form.

Comment: How about submitting it using $.ajax

Comment: I was assuming he already had in place some functionality to handle the ajax request onsubmit, but added comment to indicate where that could be achieved here too

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
      action="<?php print $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" (or) action=""
```

EDIT:

```
         <?php
         if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
             //do your validation or something here
             header("location:Process.php");

             }
```

Comment: This will just submit the form to the same page.

Comment: now check my answer ,is it correct or not?, because i improve my knowledge

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish there.

Comment: doesn't work for me though, i have no idea why but my mail() function doesn't execute even though the header sentence is after the main mail() code

Comment: you want redirect change header location

Answer (score 0):

Literally:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" id="form" target="_blank">
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This will make the browser stay on the same page, even if the form is submitted.

But you will be more likely looking for AJAX instead, [some Introduction](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/simple-ajax-php-and-javascript).

Comment: this opens the process.php file in another tab/window...? i'm not looking for that. i just want the form to submit while the user is still on the page.

Comment: @RenoYeo: Yes and I thought so. That's why I told about AJAX as well. See the linked tutorial to get a basic understanding for what you want to do.

Comment: yeah i was reading about that. i have absolutely no knowledge about AJAX, lets just hope i learn fast

Answer (score 0):

To do that you'll need jquery ajax, see here [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (with jQuery, untested)

```
$(function() {
    $("#form").submit(e) {
        // Prevent regular form submission
        e.preventDefault();

        // Submit the form via AJAX
        var $form = $("#form");
        $.post(
            $form.attr("action"),
            $form.serialize(),
            function() { alert("Done!"); }
        );
   }
}
```